# Is it possible to restore a HD that was removed from VirtualBox without a snapshot?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

I've removed the single Hard Drive (HD) from my VM (Virtual Box 4.0.6) by mistake! :S
I added the HD again, but now it loads with the base configuration (ignoring the state prior HD removal and any snapshot).

I can still see the snapshots tree and they are all there, but I didnt do a snapshot prior to the HD removal..

QUESTION: Is it possible to get the last state up and running again?

I've removed the disk this way (PT language non important):
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-4iCxcHhqe0M/UISuqMenjII/AAAAAAAAAT8/j726P30_QRA/s1600/1.png

I'm surprised that Virtual Box didn't even give me any warning about loosing data!!
After adding the disk again it acted like described above. And now (I've tried loading the disk directly from the snapshots system folder) it shows some info like this:
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BPLxUQxSlx0/UISuswjYd6I/AAAAAAAAAUE/bJ1yfKljUr8/s1600/2.png

[EDIT] - SOLVED:
I've just solved the problem by removing the current HD and adding a new HD from the snapshots folder (the most recent one, in my case a file named something like: fb85e8db-d5f4-46a9-b67b-f8fb39a99a1a.vdi.

Answer (score 0):

There is a .prev file that is created at the VM HDD location.

Sample

```
<HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{21940e73-1596-45a5-b37e-44cca5d5f1e6}" location="Windows 9.vmdk" format="VMDK" type="Normal">
          <HardDisk uuid="{df9d8522-cc5d-499c-b974-037d3f8f89fb}" location="Snapshots/{df9d8522-cc5d-499c-b974-037d3f8f89fb}.vmdk" format="VMDK"/>
          <HardDisk uuid="{b707fe0a-f50c-4bc6-b03a-d5a4fe6972fd}" location="Snapshots/{b707fe0a-f50c-4bc6-b03a-d5a4fe6972fd}.vmdk" format="VMDK">
```

You can add your custom snapshots to that. they are in a tree like fashion and the last one would be loaded. You have to remember the structure too if they were in tree like fashion.
Each snapshot is incremental so make sure the parents and children are in proper order.

Comment: I've just solved the problem by removing the current HD and adding a new HD from the snapshots folder (the most recent one, a file named fb85e8db-d5f4-46a9-b67b-f8fb39a99a1a.vdi. Everything seems to be there!! I'm so happy!! =D
I'm making backups of all my important data now and afraid to mess it all up again, so I wont try editing those files you told but will surelly have a look on them to get a depper knowledge of the inner workings!! thanks so much!!!